# How to redirect stderr to file without any buffer?

Tags: c++, linux, centos6

Does anybody know how to redirect stderr into a file without buffering in? if it is possible could you show me a simple code in c++ language for linux (Centos 6) operating system..?!

Comment: `stderr` isn't buffered by default.

Comment: I am not sure, what you want is the same as `2> stderr_file.txt` in command line?
Maybe what you need is to call your C++ program by linux script after build it, or even make the same script that build and run your program adding `2>` after your call.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: I doubt the OS cache manager will allow you to write unbuffered. You will probably have to take extra steps to flush the redirection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  freopen("file.txt", "w", stderr);

  fprintf(stderr, "output to file\n");
  return 0;
}
```

In C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  ofstream ofs("file.txt");
  streambuf* oldrdbuf = cerr.rdbuf(ofs.rdbuf());

  cerr << "output to file" << endl;

  cerr.rdbuf(oldrdbuf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cerr.rdbuf(oldrdbuf);`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with the following `dup2()` call

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    auto file_ptr = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    if (!file_ptr) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Unable to open file"};
    }

    dup2(fileno(file_ptr), fileno(stderr));
    cerr << "Write to stderr" << endl;
    fclose(file_ptr);
}
```

Comment: In the end it will write your message to file, am I right?

Comment: FirdavsbekNarzullaev Yep